# How do I connect to a remote HFS+ partition from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, hfs+

I've got a Time Capsule shared over the internet and I need to make connection to that file share.

It uses HFS+ and I can successfully connect from Mac computers.

Comment: How do you have it "shared over the internet"?

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't support HFS+ at all, so you'd need to use something else to make the share visible in Windows, such as by [using SMB](http://guides.macrumors.com/Networking_Windows_with_Mac_OS_X#Setting_up_the_Mac_to_share_files)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a list](http://www.macwindows.com/disks2.html) of commercial products for Windows that enable Windows to view and read HFS+ formatted disks. This comes courtesy of MacWindows.com. The top recommended program is Mediafour [MacDrive 8](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive). It costs $50.00 per computer and there are site licenses available.